# Playing music over Bluetooth in Android car unit that only accepts Bluetooth phone call

Tags: bluetooth, music, automotive-head-unit

I have Android car unit on Peugeot 307 SW (2007). It has Bluetooth, but it's only for making calls. I want to play music on it, and I don't want to buy any adapters.

Google Maps can tell the directions over the car's Bluetooth as Bluetooth phone call, so it should be possible for other apps to do so.

[image: Google Maps showing "Play as Bluetooth phone call" option]

Is there a way to play music over Bluetooth as Bluetooth phone call? Alternatively, are there music apps that can play music as Bluetooth phone call?

Answer (score 0):

Really, the best method is to just get a Bluetooth adapter from Amazon or something.

More apps can be integrated with regular Bluetooth and you will still be able to use the Bluetooth thing built into the car for calls. On Android, there is an option to choose what a certain bluetooth device is used for.

This would also be better than any hack or workaround because it will always be in a 'call' and will probably drain more battery. Also, an app cannot intercept all audio (which would be needed to send everything to the speakers) unless your phone is rooted.